# Checking a string for punctuation using loops

Tags: python

How do you check if a string has punctuation by using a loop. I was told to use the in operator

```
string = input("Enter a string")

for char in string:
    if char in "'.,;:?!":
        print("that string contains  punctuation")
        break 
    else:
        print("that string contains punctuation")
        break
```

Comment: @mindfolded `break` is necessary to short circuit the `for` loop once a punctuation character is found.

Comment: Your solution is almost correct. The 1st break is important, but the second one is wrong. You should put the `else` clause below the `for` instead of the `if`

Answer (score 1):

Use `string` module's `punctuation` which handles all punctuations for you:

```
import string

if any(x in string.punctuation for x in s):
    print("that string contains punctuation")      
else: 
    print("that string contains no punctuation")
```

where `s` is your string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `for-else` construct to print the message that the string does not contain punctuation if it finishes the loop without finding one:

```
string = input("Enter a string")

for char in string:
    if char in "'.,;:?!":
        print("that string contains punctuation")
        break 
else:
    print("that string does not contain punctuation")
```

Answer (score 0):

That code is half right.

The `if` part is correct, because as soon as you find any punctuation, your goal is met and you don't need to keep looking, so you can correctly `break` out of the loop.

However the `else` part is wrong, because if the current character is not punctuation, you still have to keep looking -- the remainder of the string might have punctuation.    Also the message is wrong; it should say the string **doesn't** have punctuation.

You can restructure the code to take advantage of the `for/else` construct:

```
string = input("Enter a string")

for char in string:
    if char in "'.,;:?!":
        print("that string contains punctuation")
        break
else:
    print("that string does not contain punctuation")
```

The `else` will execute if the loop makes it all the way to the end of the string without calling `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Or Check the other way round considering the string input would be longer than the punctuation string

```
string = input("Enter a string")

punch_string= "'.,;:?!"
for char in punch_string:
    if char in string:
        print("that string contains punctuation")
        break
else:
    print("that string does not contain punctuation")
```

A shorter version using set intersection

```
    if set(string).intersection(set("'.,;:?!" )):
        print("that string contains punctuation")
else:
    print("that string does not contain punctuation")
```